# GPG error: "The following signatures were invalid" on Docker installation with cURL

Tags: raspbian, curl, gpg

I'm trying to install docker on my Raspberry Pi 4b (raspian 10 buster), but get this error on running the installation command as listed [on the official website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/):

```
 ~ > sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: f45d7c11389849ff46a6b4d94e0dd1ffebca32c1
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
W: GPG error: http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB
E: The repository 'http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie InRelease' is not signed.
```

This is the first time I got this error, and different to similar questions here it doesn apear with `apt update`/`apt upgrade`. The error hints at a problem with `mariadb`, but, although I had some problems installing it, it is now running without any problems on version `10.3`

Any ideas on how I can fix the invalid signatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some issues installing Raspberry Pi as well, the one that helped me the most was the one from Docker Wiki:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/.

However, your issue seems to be lying with the repo itself. In the URL you can see that it's a repository for Jessie and not for Buster. 
You should check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all the contents in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, maybe even resetting them to the default.